# Spark JavaRdd / DataFrame / DataSet to XML

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, xml-parsing, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-xml

I want to convert spark JavaRdd/ Dataframe / Dataset to xml. I have analyzed spark-xml from DataBrics this repo was last released in Nov 2016 (0.4.1 version) and i doubt its compatiblity with new version of DSE and Spark.

IS there any alternative of spark-xml ??

Spark-xml https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **scala.xml.XML** package?